# AzureAD - Multiple sites/applications organization

Tags: azure-active-directory, microsoft-graph-api

Hopefully someone can help me get my head around this one.

As an example, I have a single AzureAD tenant with 4 users, 4 enterprise applications and 4 locations connect via Oauth2.

User1 may need access to App1 at Location1.
User1 may also need access to App2 and App3 at Location2.
It is possible for all apps to be available a location.

I am looking for the best possible way to organize this in AzureAD. My app will query for data /grant access using Graph API.

Any help would be great

Cheers

Answer (score 0):

Yes this can be possible you just need to create a conditional access policies under `tenant->Secuirity->Conditional Access`.

> User1 may need access to App1 at Location1. User1 may also need access
> to App2 and App3 at Location2. It is possible for all apps to be
> available a location

**for this scenario you need to create two conditions access policy for same user one for App1 at Location1 and second for App2 and App3 at Location2**

[image]

[image]

[image]

You can refer this [***Document***](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/active-directory/conditional-access/howto-conditional-access-policy-all-users-mfa) to create a plocies for a Named Location

Comment: I don't think this gives me what I am after. I do not want to define conditional locations and I want it easy to add/remove a location from an app going forward. App collections probably would have helped but for some reason I can't query collection data in graph api